# How do I know which edition install disc I need to repair a non-booting Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, bootrepair, system-repair-disc

When a Windows 7 install doesn't start I need an installation disc in order to repair it. If I use a disc of an edition of Windows 7 that doesn't match the installed edition it will refuse to do a repair (that's my experience the last times I've tried).

By edition I mean all of this seem to have to match exactly:

- 32/64 bit
- **Windows 7/Windows 7 N**
- Home/Pro
- **Language**

I'm sure there are **even more variables that need to match**, for unknown reasons.

How do I determine which edition install/repair disc to use without being able to start the target OS?

##### Update

I'm not sure exactly how to clarify the difference between this question and the proposed one, because to me it's already clearly listed in bullet form: N/not N, language, and potential *additional unknown variables* that can prevent a repair. I have boldfaced these things in the list.

The proposed question asks "Is there a way I can look up which version of Windows (Home, Professional)". I don't see how that is enough in this context, but I'm open to assertions or explanations of how N-ness and language doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Do you know anything about the installation? Is this an actual problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @Ramhound I have access to it, but I don't know much about it since I've forgotten the details. It's probably 64 bit Pro, and either Swedish or English. It's an actual problem — it refuses to boot, with `0x000000f4` and as usual Windows fails to actually repair Windows in a hundred invocations of `sfc` from a hundred different install media.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Ubuntu ISO and use the live boot function to boot repair (might not be helpful in your case) But here's a mad idea. Once you launch Ubuntu, install Wine and go to your Windows C:/Windows/System32 and launch Winver from there??

Even if that doesn't work, you can at least have access to your Windows files and may try an fix it in the other way.

Else, there are some boot ISO disks which you can flash to a USB drive and fix windows using it. Windows AIO is one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I can plug it into a number of Win10/7/Xp/Ubuntu/macOS machines and do pretty much anything I want. Problem is, I have no idea what's actually wrong apart from the 0xF4 error code, so I don't know what else I can do than to use an install disc. I tried finding out which files were corrupt using `sfc` and replace them from some install disc, but no luck. Now I can't even seem to get a proper log after running `sfc` so I feel like I'm at a dead end there ‍♂️

Comment: Sorry about not being familiar with winver.exe, but how do I point it to the correct Windows installation, whether I run it using Wine or another Windows installation? I don't think an actual Windows installation drive will work as a Wine prefix (and is that even non-destructive?) I don't want it to display info about the environment it's executed in.